# How to change a vector item in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I've got a vector of structs in C++ and I would like to modify each item individually. I found that doing `SomeStruct info = myVector[i]` gives me a copy of the item, so if I modify it nothing will be changed. So right now I'm resetting the item like that: `myVector[i] = info`. Is there a more efficient way do that? One that won't involve a copy operation?

This is my current code:

```
struct CharacterInfo {
    QChar character;
    int occurrences;
    double frequency;
};

std::vector<CharacterInfo> characterInfos;

// Some code to populate the vector

for (unsigned i = 0; i < characterInfos.size(); i++) {
    CharacterInfo info = characterInfos[i];
    info.frequency = (double)info.occurrences / (double)totalOccurrences;
    characterInfos[i] = info; // how to avoid this?
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way which doesn't change too much of your code is just to use a reference instead of an instance. So:

```
SomeStruct & info = myVector[i];
```

The next easiest way is to change from using a loop with an index, so like:

```
for (std::vector<SomeStruct>::iterator it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); ++it)
{
    SomeStruct & info = *it;
    // do stuff here
}
```

With the STL you can go even further, especially if you have a C++11 capable compiler, for instance:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(myVector), std::end(myVector), [](SomeStruct & info) { /* do stuff here */ });
```

Also not related to your question directly, but if you add a method to the struct that computes the frequency, the code becomes much cleaner, for instance following from the last example you could do:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(myVector), std::end(myVector), std::mem_fun(&SomeStruct::calculateFrequency));
```

This will also work without a C++11 compiler if you change the calls to `std::begin(myVector)` with `myVector.begin()` and the same for end.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a reference:

```
CharacterInfo& info = characterInfos[i];
info.frequency = (double)info.occurrences / (double)totalOccurrences;
```

The reference `info` is bound to the element of your vector. If you change it, you change
the vector element too.

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate through the vector with an STL iterator:

```
for (vector<CharacterInfo>::iterator it = characterInfos.begin();
        it != characterInfos.end(); ++it) {
    it->frequency = (double)it->occurrences / totalOccurrences;
}
```

In the loop, `it` is an iterator that has basically same functionality and interface as a pointer to a `CharacterInfo` struct: http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/

Looping with an iterator is the more idiomatic way of iterating through each element of a `std::vector` if you don't need to know the index of each element.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question but I think you are trying to do this?

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < characterInfos.size(); i++) {
    characterInfos[i].frequency = (double)characterInfos[i].occurrences / (double)totalOccurrences;
}
```

Another option would be to use iterators:

```
for(std::vector<CharacterInfo>::iterator it = characterInfos.begin(); it != characterInfos.end(); ++it){
    it->frequency = (double)it->occurences / (double)totalOccurences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is a very old question. For "newer" c++, the same can be done with [Range-based for loop (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for(auto &characterInfo : characterInfos) {
    characterInfo.frequency = characterInfo.occurences / static_cast<double>(totalOccurences);
}
```